# Basic question regarding returning values from user-defined functions

Tags: function-construction, core-language

I'm new to Mathematica today. I would like to write a function that will implement the following pseudocode:

```
f[x_]:=
  Do something 
  return y
```

I have searched the documentation, but I'm still very confused. How do I return a variable after some complicated procedure? Use `Return`? It doesn't work sometimes.

Comment: Don't use `Return`. Just have the result you want to return be the last thing in your function.

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/40-defining-your-own-functions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this (just a contrived example)

```
f[x_] := Module[{y},
   y = {1, x, x^2};
   Return[y]];
```

but the `Return` is not needed so you can do this

```
f[x_] := Module[{y},
   y = {1, x, x^2};
   y];
```

also and, in fact, you can simplify it to this

```
f[x_] := Module[{y},
   y = {1, x, x^2}];
```

or perhaps if you want to, even just this

```
f[x_] := {1, x, x^2};
```

but you will want to read the tutorials for more details.

For local variables you may want to read about the differences between `Module`, `Block` and `With`. Of course, you could also use global variables if you want to do so.

Comment: Why not just `f[x_] = {1, x, x^2}`?

Comment: Looks cool! Why one has to use Module to localize all the variables inside a function (I mean, of course, this is a principle for functions)? Is there any other way to do this without Module?

Comment: And why not a pure function: f = {1, #, #^2} &;   Then there is nothing to localize.

Comment: @bills Perhaps it can be used in some cases, but "Do something; return y" is not specific. It could be very complicated code.